# Как получить данные из основного процесса в дочернем?

Tags: java, multiprocessing

Есть основной процесс Main. В нем вызывается другой процесс ChildMain. Я хочу организовать обмен данным между процессами, я могу передать из Main данные через `getOutputStream()`, но как эти данные получить в ChildMain?

Main процесс

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec("javac -cp src  src\\child\\ChildMain.java");

        System.out.println("Start...");

         process = Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec("java -cp src child.ChildMain");

        BufferedWriter output= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
        output.write(300);

    }
```

ChildMain процесс

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Получение данных из Main

    }
```

Comment: В `ChildMain` просто читать `System.in`.

Comment: Через Scanner ?

Comment: Как удобнее. `in` - это статическое поле типа `InputStream`. Если в этом примере пишите байтами через `write`, то и читать можно байтами через `read`. Если передавать примитивы и строки, то можно и через `Scanner`. Если передавать достаточно сложные, но сериализируемые данные, то можно использовать `ObjectOutputStream` и `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: Спасибо,  я попробовал по разному принять данные, но не выходи

Comment: `Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        w.write(12);` вот так я отправляю данные из Main процесса. А так принимаю  `Reader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` но не работает.  Совсем запутался

Comment: `OutputStreamWriter` имеет внутренний буфер. Нужно сбрасывать руками при помощи `flush`.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает как часики. Огромное спасибо